# Dropwizard 4.0.1: query param value parsing without using any annotation

Tags: java, null, dropwizard, query-string

To be specified, my question is how I can make "null" query parameter value to null.

For example, I wrote my resource like this.

```
@GET  
public FooView bar(@QueryParam("city") String name) {  
  if (name != null) {  
    return Response.ok.build();  
  } else {  
    throw new RuntimeException("city name cannot be null");
  }  
}
```

And queried like this.

```
http://localhost:blahblah?city=null
```

Then name will be "null" String. What I want is without using any annotation or adding "null".equals(name), is there a way to make "null" string null?

I've tried ParamConverterProvider and Filter but problem not solved.

Comment: I don't think that is possible . Think of a scenario where a city name is actually null.Jersey treats the absence of passed parameter as 'NULL'.

Comment: The best I could think of was to check the query param(is there is a defined set) and mark to default if the value doesn't fit. OR as already marked by you, compare with a `"null"` instead and then perform actions

Comment: It's been a while... but thanks anyway @k1133 !
We decided not to send city !